# How to center items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to have a horizontal RecyclerView that I can insert or remove items from. The items should be aligned to the center. Instead, they are stuck to the left side.

***Note:*** I cannot use `android:layout_width=wrap_content`, as suggested in other questions, since a change in the RV size will cause misbehaving animations (i.e items sliding in from "outside the RV" on item removal).

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/other_view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/another_view"/>


layoutManager = new 
LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);        
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
...
//updating the data on insert\remove: 
DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(
                            new MyCallback(newItems, oldItems));
diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(myAdapter);
```

...

Any ideas?

Comment: You item layout is the best place to centralize your items

Comment: @Whales_Corps how will it affect their position within the RV?

Comment: simply centralize  your Item view or  use ConstraintLayout and set Properties like start to start of parent and end to end of parent it will set your recycle-view to center

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi you are right, that is what i'm doing. My question is- How to align the items INSIDE the RV in the middle?

Comment: @lea.cotan, I think you're mis interpreting what you want!
You have unknown amount of columns in your RC and those column have child views inside of it, so the child views can be three, four or five, and those are what you want to position to the center? let say there are 4 child views in a column, you want them centralized and when ever one of this child view is gone/removed, you want the column to rearrange it children and position then to the center. is that it?

Comment: @Whales_Corps
Sounds right. as long as I have less items in the RecyclerView then the screen width, I want them to be positioned in the center of the RecyclerView, and not to the left.

Comment: @lea.cotan if your itemView is in ConstraintLayout use its property start to start of parent and end to end of parent it will align item in center

Answer (score 0):

> Let your RecyclerView width match_parent if nothing else is to share the space with it.
>
> **Like below**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

> **Then the item layout that you're using in the adapter can look like below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_card1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"> <!--this can be any size-->

    <TextView
        style="@style/regularText"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="@string/cardNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

> The good thing is that your recycler view only render one itemlayout per column and so what we did is to extend the item layout to fill the whole column.
>
> ANY QUESTION?
>
> **OPP!!! I think I miss translate your question!!!***
>
> **NEW ANSWER JUST IF I ACTUALLY MISUNDERSTAND IN THE FIRST ONE**

I think you need a GridLayoutManager.

Meanwhile, you need to know the amount of item that will be displayed in a row.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. My RV should have more than one item per column, displayed in a row.
Due to changing items, I cannot know how many fit on the screen.

Comment: More than one item in a column??? can you show a sample image of this?

Comment: Even so, you still have to do it in your itemsLayout, it's obvious the RV has nothing to do with it.